# In excel, how to return nearest cell that contains date

Tags: excel

I have a column that contains text cells and date cells. Next to each cell of text, I need the nearest cell that is above that text and contains a date to be returned.

***Example***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:A1,MATCH(1,$A$1:A1,-1))/(ISTEXT(A1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a column agent (English is my second language so please give me a better way to describe it if you know), let's say column C.
Put this formula to C1:

```
=A1
```

Put this formula to C2 and fill down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATE(DAY(A2),MONTH(A2),YEAR(A2))), C1, A2)
```

The above formula check if `A2` is a date then copy it or fill it down by the cell above.

Copy the cells you want in column B (`B2:B4,...`) from column C. Hide column C if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1),AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:$A$10,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,">1/1/1900")),"")
```

[image]

If there are numbers also in cells rather that names then you can use below formula

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="D","",AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:$A$10,COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,">1/1/1900")))
```

Comment: Remember you have to apply format as `Date` cells where putting formulas. Otherwise it will show only number value of dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `LOOKUP` function:

```
B1: =IF(ISNUMBER(A1),"",LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A1),$A$1:A1))
```

and fill down.

[image]